# Delay method call for specific time

Tags: c++, linux, ros

I'm writing a ros node with c++ and need to delay one method call a specific time.
What is a good way to do that, without locking up the node for that delay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sehe used a C++ approach, instead exist two ways of doing this within ROS.

The first - simpler to implement method - is to use [`Rate`](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rostime/html/classros_1_1Rate.html) class. Section 2 of [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time) clarifies how to use it. However as you can see there, this is not the best choice.

> **Note**: It is generally recommended to use Timers instead of Rate.

[`Timers`](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1Timer.html) are the proper way to wait for a certain amount of time while doing other stuffs. [This simple tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp_tutorials/Tutorials/Timers) explains how to use them.

```
ros::Timer ros::NodeHandle::createTimer(ros::Duration period, <callback>, bool oneshot = false);
```

In your case if you want to execute the method just once, set the `oneshot` bool variable to true.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. you have other threads or processes that can progress. Simply sleep your thread for a bit:

   ```
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(150));
   ```
2. you have other tasks that need to progress on the same thread. Look at asynchronous execution, e.g. with `Boost Asio`